# How to make iOS slow

Tags: ios, testing

I'm a mobile QA. Now we have an issue about a race condition between network response and UI rendering. We guess if the UI rendering is slower than the network response, then it will crash.

We already tried to speed up the network response, by using Charles' map local feature. But the duration is still about 20ms. This is the best way we can think to speed up the network.

So I'm asking if there is any way to slow down the UI rendering on iOS, real device or simulator. Is there a way to set the CPU usage or memory for iOS? Or if there is a way to keep the iOS system in high CPU / memory usage?

Comment: Better to just preload the UI or call the request after UI is finished rendering, rather than trying to do something like that, app can crash if viewController have not enter atleast viewDidLoad stage

Comment: @Tj3n, thanks for your reply. I'm a QA, so my job is making the crash. We now see a small percentage of our users meet this crash, I want to reproduce this crash bug and then I can verify our fix from developers.

Comment: Have you tried the thread sanitizer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you add to the application many background tasks, which will execute on CPU and GPU.
This tasks should execute on background concurrent thread and do not interact with the main code of the application.
For example you can create NSOperation which will calculate some value < pseudocode >:

```
    <in the operation's main>
    - (void)main{

       double value = 100000009900.0
       for (int i = 0; i<INT_MAX; i++)
       {
         value = sqrt(value) + rand(time())
       }
    }
```

and add operations, that will doing something with GPU < pseudocode >:

```
<in GPU' operation>
- (void)main{

   CIImage* image = <load image>;
  CIFilter* filter = <some complicated filter>;
  filter.inputImage = image;
  CIImage* result = filter.outputImage;
  CIContext* context = <create context or share same for all operations>

  NSData* imageData = [context JPEGRepresentationOfImage:result colorSpace:NULL options:nil];
  CGImageRef image = [context renderImage];
  if (image)
  {
     CGImageRelease(image);
  }

}
```

After that add many operations to a queue. For this you should add some button to the interface.
I understand, what this is a special application, but if you create all right, you will get right result. (Sometimes I do that to check memory pressure and performance issues)

Also you can use old mac and run the application on the simulator.